# Does get() retrieve the actual object?

Tags: r

Could anyone explain the behavior below?

```
df <- data.frame(dog = 1:5)

colnames(df) <- "cat" # This works
colnames( get('df') ) <- "cat" # error
colnames( eval(parse(text='df')) ) <- "cat" # error
```

The error is

```
Error in colnames(get("df")) <- "cat" : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Comment: [`df`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Fdist.html) is a standard function; your code shadows it's definition; `df` is not a good name for a global variable.

Comment: ah the problems of working on a small screen! Thanks for linkong that @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` retrieve the actual object, but that is not why the code does not work.

Note that

```
x <- get('df')
colnames(x) <- 'cat'
```

does work but that

```
get('df') <- 34
```

and

```
sqrt(4) <- 2
```

do not work.

The reason that they do not work is because of the order in which R evaluates things ([see here for the actual C code that produced the error](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/56becd21c75d104bfec829f9c23baa2e144869a2/src/main/eval.c#L1638-L1666)).  R is expanding `colnames(x)` into

```
get('df') <- `colnames<-`(x, y)
```

This is not valid, like `get('df') <- 34` or `sqrt(4)`, because you cannot assign the result of a function call to value.

Answer (score -1):

Please use assign

```
assign(names(eval(as.name("df"))), "cat")
```

The reason `parse(text='df')` will not work is because it returns an expression that is evaluated by eval and for deails please see the answer @Thomas linked to!

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question at hand

Comment: I guess I got carried away in trying to help the OP set the names!